# Change traces.plot label from date to hours

Tags: python

I'm currently plotting a time series where I have a `datetime` and values. According to their [documentation](https://traces.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html#quickstart-using-traces) they have hours on the `xlabel` but when I try to replicate the graph it displays the date. How can I change what `traces.plot` displays?

The code that I'm using is this:

```
import traces
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


time_series = traces.TimeSeries()
time_series[datetime(2042, 2, 1,  6,  0,  0)] = 0 #  6:00:00am
time_series[datetime(2042, 2, 1,  7, 45, 56)] = 1 #  7:45:56am
time_series[datetime(2042, 2, 1,  8, 51, 42)] = 0 #  8:51:42am
time_series[datetime(2042, 2, 1, 12,  3, 56)] = 1 # 12:03:56am
time_series[datetime(2042, 2, 1, 12,  7, 13)] = 0 # 12:07:13am

time_series.plot()
plt.show()
```

And the `Figure 1` is the result (The blue graph is the doc's one and the one I need):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to set the datetime format of x-axis.

for format string of datetime, you can check here [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```py
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
...
fig, ax = time_series.plot()
date_form = DateFormatter("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
plt.show()
```